# How to flip a box2d body when it can't move forward? LibGDX

Tags: libgdx, physics, box2d, movement

I'm attempting to create a simple enemy for a platformer. It should move forward constantly until it hits something like a wall, and then it should flip and move forward the other direction. How might I accomplish this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few ways you can achieve this.

Detecting point of collision on the `Body`, using a `ContactListener` you can listen to the contacts and react to them, by comparing the contact point from the `WorldManifold` to the world center of your `Body` you can determine if the collision happened on a side of the `Body` (rather than for example the bottom).

Another approach could be to add two `Fixture`s to the `Body`, one a little to the left and one a little to the right, then listen for contacts on them, this approach has the advantage of you not having to compare contact points as you know which side collided.